# click and move UIViewController over second UIViewController

Tags: ios

I want to apologize in advance. I am a really new using xcode. My objective c terminology is severely lacking. This may have been answered before but I can't find it. I have two UIViewControllers one above the other one. I want to be able to click and drag the top view controller around my screen to place it in a new location (I have provided a screen shot).

[image]

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Thanks in advance,

Marc

Comment: Hey Marc, is the area definitely a UIViewController or just a UIView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please explain clearly!!!

ViewController is a controller that includes a view ([see more MVC - software architecture pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller))

You can drag a View but dragging ViewController is not logic!

If you want to drag a View, you should overwrite the following method of UIResponed:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

Good luck

Comment: Thank you NtVietHung. Sorry, I could not explain it more clearly (I just started iOS a couple of weeks ago.), but you got it. I just got rid of my ViewController and made it an UIView instead. With these functions you provided I was able to move it around. Thanks again! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah, I saw it. objective-C is very interesting. You should read ebook about it, you will see it! :)